# How to refactor C# interpolated strings to string.Format(...) automatically?

Tags: c#, string

Recently in C# 6 a new language element/syntactic sugar was introduced named string interpolation.

However after a few minutes of enjoying the sweet taste of this syntax, it quickly turns out, that interpolated strings (what are still string literals in semantic point of view) can not be refactored out to a resource because of the variables embedded are living only that scope where the interpolated string is defined.

This scope locked string literals for example can not be localized and regardless of the localization need, some code quality checkers used to regard string literals embedded in as code smell.

Working with a huge enterprise code base I expect to appear more and more interpolated strings, so the problem will be quickly turn from theoretical to practical. I would like both

- have a code quality checker rule which bans out this practice just
  like string literals in the middle of the code (*I can manage it, by
  defining custom rules in the standard quality tools. Although StyleCop currently does not even recognize them, and runs to an internal error, so this will not be as easy as it sounds*)
- have a refactoring tool what can refactor
  string interpolation to string.Format so then it can easily can
  refactor out to a standard .NET resource.

Any suggestions

Comment: ReSharper probably allows you to change between the formats. Usually if it can convert from A to B it lets you convert from B to A. Or just write a new Roslyn analyser!

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Writing a custom code transformation Roslyn seems to be a bit overwhelming task, plus I do no want to reinvent the wheel. Thx anyway

Comment: What do you mean "automatically"? You want to write a program that will convert interpolated strings to String.Format()?

Comment: @sweeper I mean a refactoring tool. Ideally this could check the code base in the build server, but less ideally can refactor this smell project/solution wide by a few click.

Comment: Are you sure about this? `String interpolation is transformed at compile time to invoke an equivalent string.Format call. This leaves in place support for localization as before (though still with traditional format strings) and doesn’t introduce any post compile injection of code via strings.`, taken from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/Dn879355.aspx

Comment: @tzachs Thanks for pointing this. It's amazing how hollow could be the official documentation. Besides of this sentence is not explained (I mean 'how'?) it is a contradiction within itself. How can we localize a string, which does not even exist in our source? For localizing it we must provide different language versions...

Comment: I have used interpolation with *expressions*, not constant values, and they definitely work. If you use something like `$"My name is {project.resources.Name}"` then it should work.

Comment: Oh never mind ... I see what you're saying. You want the whole string to be localizable ... what would have been `String.Format("My Name is {0}", myName)` should be `String.Format(project.resources.Introduction, myName)`.

Comment: @RossPresser: exactly

Answer (score 2):

Enabling code analysis prevents usage of interpolated strings (warning [CA1305](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182190.aspx)) as they don't support specifying locale (unlike `String.Format`). So while somewhat awkward this is possible solution to your particular case.

Also R# can quickly convert one format to another - so while not automated combination of Code Analysis and R# would let you quickly find and partially correct all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Localisation is possible with string interpolation.

Consider this:

```
System.FormattableString s = $"Hello, {name}";
```

s.ToString() will use the current culture to produce the string.

```
float flt = 3.141;

System.IFormattable s = $"{flt}";
```

With IFormattable you can alter numeric formats according to specific languages

So it **is** possible, just not directly.

source:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: Localization is not only about to get the correct decimal separator and other culture specific settings. It is also about to use resources to get language specific versions of strings. My statement was: "can not be refactored out to a resource because of the variables embedded are living only that scope where the interpolated string is defined.", which is true. Using interpolated strings is sweet, but a code smell.