# Use regex to convert Interpolated string to string.Format

Tags: c#, regex

Me and my colleague have different versions of VisualStudio. He used interpolated string and I couldn't build the solution and had to convert them all to string.Format.

Now I thought it might be good exercise for regex.

So how to convert this:

```
$"alpha: {alphaID}, betaValue: {beta.Value}"
```

To this:

```
string.Format("alpha: {0}, betaValue: {1}", alphaID, beta.Value)
```

Now the number of variables can vary (let's say 1 - 20, but should be generic)

I came up with this regex, to match the first variable

```
\$.*?{(\w+)}
```

but I couldn't figure out how to repeat the part after dollar sign, so I can repeat the result.

Comment: Do you know you also need to account for `{{` and `}}` literal braces? That is not the best job for a regex to parse code. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648824/how-to-refactor-c-sharp-interpolated-strings-to-string-format-automatically

Comment: Also tell him to configure his version of VS such that the code does not make use of C#6 features. That is possible.

Comment: How should something like `string.Format($"alpha: {alphaID}, {0}, betaValue: {1} {beta.Value}", varOne, varTwo)` be handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Regex.Replace` has an overload which takes a function, called the `MatchEvaluator`. You might use it like this;

```
 var paramNumber = 0;     
 var idNames = new List<string>();
 myCSharpString = Regex.Replace(myCSharpString, match => {
    // remember the id inside brackets;
    idNames.Add(match.ToString());

    // return "0", then "1", etc.
    return (paramNumber++).ToString();
 });
```

At the end of this process, your string like `"this is {foo} not {bar}"` will have been replaced to `"this is {0} not {1}"` and you will have a list containing `{ "foo" , "bar" }` which you can use to assemble the parameter list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use C#6 features in older version of visual studio [using the C# 6 nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016203/6722)

Essentially, just use

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

On all the projects.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have experience in `c#` but this may help you:

`\{(.+)}\gU`

**Explanation**

`{ matches the character { literally`

`. matches any character (except newline)`

`Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, 
expanding as needed [lazy]`

`} matches the character } literally`

`g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)`

`U modifier: Ungreedy`

Comment: I don't think this malformed PCRE regex can help much in C#.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I can just enter the code in notepad++ or other regex substitute tool and run it. I will get rid of  \gU and insert lazy operator (?) after plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few options that do not involve regex:

1. You can use ReSharper. It has such conversions built in.
2. Write your custom code fix with Roslyn if you don't want to pay for ReSharper. [Here is an example](https://github.com/DustinCampbell/CSharpEssentials/blob/master/Source/CSharpEssentials/ConvertToInterpolatedString/ConvertToInterpolatedStringRefactoring.cs) that does from `string.format` to interpolated string, you  just have to reverse it.
3. Do it manually
4. Ask your colleague to do it for you if he can.
5. Update VS